# Callback problems with WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, callback

I've been running into a Callback problems with async programming in WPF .Net 4.5.
There should be a way of doing this code in a more understandable way (I have suppressed a big part of it to make it easier to see what is going on).

I don't think there is a way to simply remove code because I need to call Dispatcher in order to manipulate WPF controls and calls like in `TbSequence.Focus()` and `Utils.ShowMessageBox`.

```
private void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Controller.Busy = true;

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Controller.SaveItem();
            }
            catch (BdlDbException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ExceptionSubType == DbExceptionSubTypes.UniqueViolation)
                {
                    HandleUniqueViolation(ex);
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorMessage = "";
                    errorMessage = ex.Message;
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Utils.ShowMessageBox(t_MessageBox.Attention, errorMessage)));
                }
            }

            Controller.Busy = false;
        });
    }
    catch (FieldException ex)
    {
        if (ex.FieldName == "FirstName")
        {
            TbFirstName.ValidationError = true;
            TbFirstName.ApplyErrorToolTip(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public void Init(UcEdit container, Employee entity = null)
{
    Controller.Busy = true;

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Controller.Init(entity);
        }
        catch (BdlEntryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            HandleNotFoundException(ex);
        }

        Container.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Container.DataContext = Controller;

            // Instructions order for focusing TbSequence after load should be different in case we have an existent item
            // because we have to focus the control AFTER it is filled with data, in order to set the caret position correctly.
            if (Controller.IsNewItem)
            {
                this.DataContext = Controller;
                TbSequence.Focus();
                Controller.Busy = false;
            }
            else
            {
                TbSequence.TextChanged += TbSequence_TextChanged;
                this.DataContext = Controller;
                SetButtons();
            }
        }));
    });
}

private void HandleUniqueViolation(BdlDbException ex)
{
    string errorMessage = "";
    bool isSequence = false; // if true, it's name.

    if (ex.Fields[1] == "Sequence")
    {
        errorMessage = "There is already an Employee with the sequence \"" + Controller.Item.Sequence + "\".";
        isSequence = true;
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage = "There is already an Employee named \"" + Controller.Item.FirstName +
        " " + Controller.Item.LastName + "\".";
    }

    errorMessage += "\r\nLoad it from Database?\r\n(All the changes on this window will be lost.)";

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBoxResult res = Utils.ShowMessageBox(t_MessageBox.Question, errorMessage, MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

        switch (res)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                if (isSequence)
                {
                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Controller.GetEmployeeBySequence(Controller.Item.Sequence);
                            Init(Container, Controller.OriginalItem);
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Controller.GetEmployeeByName(Controller.Item.FirstName, Controller.Item.LastName);
                            Init(Container, Controller.OriginalItem);
                        });
                }
                break;

            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                break;
        }
    }));
}
```

As you can see, there is a major Callback problem here that behaves like this:

```
Save_Executed (UI) -> HandleUniqueViolation (Task) -> ShowMessageBox (UI) -> Controller.GetEmployeeBySequence (Task) -> Controller.Init ...
```

And so it goes.
Is there a way to make this code more easy to read?
Thank you.

Comment: The original name of the question was "Callback Hell with WPF".
Mr Dean Kuga edited it saying that "there is no need for such language". I disagree, since "Callback Hell" is a well known term used for chains of callbacks that become "unmaintainable". "Callback problems" is way too generic and don't actually nearly give a good hint of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting off your code by putting (more or less) the entirety of your method body in a call to `Task.Run` and then explicitly marshalling to the UI thread all over the place within that callback.

Just narrow the scope of your `Task.Run` call so that your UI code is just outside the call to `Run` rather than inside both it and a call to `Invoke`:

```
private async void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Controller.Busy = true;

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Controller.SaveItem());
            }
            catch (BdlDbException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ExceptionSubType == DbExceptionSubTypes.UniqueViolation)
                {
                    HandleUniqueViolation(ex);
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorMessage = "";
                    errorMessage = ex.Message;
                    Utils.ShowMessageBox(t_MessageBox.Attention, errorMessage);
                }
            }

            Controller.Busy = false;
    }
    catch (FieldException ex)
    {
        if (ex.FieldName == "FirstName")
        {
            TbFirstName.ValidationError = true;
            TbFirstName.ApplyErrorToolTip(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you're running the actual long running business operation that you have in a thread pool thread, but doing all of your error handling in the UI thread.

You can do the same thing throughout your application.  Rather than putting *everything* into a background thread and then explicitly marshaling, just only ever execute operations in a background thread that should be *entirely* executed in a background thread.